# instaloader - validate login to ensure logged in with python module

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using instaloader to gather some data about my instagram account.

I wrote a very basic loop to get my followers and it worked great:

```
 # Get instance
import instaloader
L = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Login or load session
L.login("myuser", "mypass")        # (login)
#L.load_session_from_file(myaccount)


# Obtain profile metadata
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, "testaccount")

# Print list of followees

follow_list = []
count=0
file = open("output.txt","a+")
for followee in profile.get_followers():
    username = followee.username , followee.external_url
    file.write(username + "\n")
    print(username)
file.close()
```

I tried it on a random bigger account with ~2000 followers on it, just to see it's performance against my test account which has 10 followers to keep it simple.

and I got the error

```
Requests within last 10/11/20/22/30/60 minutes grouped by type:
 *                            other:    1    1    1    1    1    1
Instagram responded with HTTP error "429 - Too Many Requests". Please
do not run multiple instances of Instaloader in parallel or within
short sequence. Also, do not use any Instagram App while Instaloader
is running.
The request will be retried in 666 seconds, at 09:18.
```

I saw this in the FAQ and troubleshooting section of instaloader and it seems to suggest that this is more common if you're not logged in, so I started wondering if my login was actually working.

I created a session file with the commandline interface

```
instaloader -login testuser
```

which worked and created a session file

```
dev@cab:~/test2 $ ls -la ~/.config/instaloader/session-testuser
```

I updated the example code

```
 # Get instance
import instaloader
L = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Login or load session
#L.login("myuser", "mypass")        # (login)
L.load_session_from_file(testuser)


# Obtain profile metadata
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, "testaccount")

# Print list of followees

follow_list = []
count=0
file = open("output.txt","a+")
for followee in profile.get_followers():
    username = followee.username , followee.external_url
    file.write(username + "\n")
    print(username)
file.close()
```

however when I then try the script I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gram2.py", line 7, in <module>
    L.load_session_from_file(testuser)
NameError: name 'testuser' is not defined
```

from what I've read, but couldn't be sure on the documentation, but did fine examples online I don't need to specify the path to the session file, just the username, and it should automatically look in $user/.conf/instaloader for the session file, so I'm not sure why the session file isn't working, but this then makes me think more that my initial concern that login isn't working is true.

how do I debug / confirm the login is working?

Comment: this was my first post, I thought it was relevant to the machine learning community who may be using the same software, there is no need to throw words around like 'spam' and there was certainly no reason to edit the post beyond removing an incorrect tag. This is not a welcoming approach to a new user to the platform trying to post a useful question.

Comment: Apologies if I sounded rude - this was not my intention. Welcome to SO. Please notice the [usage](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info) of the `machine-learning` tag, and that tags have to do with the content of the question, not its context; please also notice that editing posts for improving their readability (e.g. by removing conversational & other elements irrelevant to the question) is a standard practice here, and it should not be interpreted differently.

Comment: Also please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @stacker note that it's common to edit questions in this way.  it also looks like a simple typo to me, you just want quotes, i.e. as a string `"testuser"`, and you don't want to refer to the user via a variable called `testuser`

Comment: that was it, the missing quotes, treating the username as a string, great spot.

Comment: ```load_session_from_file``` takes two arguments first one is username witch is positional and the second one is optional filename(the session file path)

Answer (score 1):

The error refers to `L.load_session_from_file(testuser)`, you have to pass the username as string,so try `L.load_session_from_file("testuser")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define testuser as you have passed it as a variable, to fix it pack it inside : `"testuser"`.

Hope that fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just on the command line, no () in below, just for info sake.
instaloader (profiles to download) --login (username) --sessionfile session-(file name) --stories --no-profile-pic --no-posts --no-videos

error: Loaded session from c:\users\Darth\appdata\local\temp/.instaloader-darth/session-(username).
JSON Query to graphql/query: HTTP error code 401. [retrying; skip with ^C]
JSON Query to graphql/query: HTTP error code 401. [retrying; skip with ^C]
Fatal error: JSON Query to graphql/query: HTTP error code 401.